# Mocking Method Execution Times and Sequence

Tags: c#, .net, moq

I am using Moq paired with an Interface of methods. I need to test that the methods in this interface are executed in a certain sequence as well as a certain number of times for each one.

## Interface

```
public interface IInterface
{
    void MethodOne(string foo);
    void MethodTwo(string foo);
}
```

## Method

```
// MyClass stuff ...

public async Task Run()
{
    MethodOne("foo");
    MethodTwo("foo");
}

// ...
```

## Tests

I've written this test to verify that the methods are only executed a certain amount of times (once):

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
    var mockSequence = new MockSequence();

    var obj = new MyClass();
    await obj.Run();

    mock.Verify(i=> i.MethodOne("foo"), Times.Once());
    mock.Verify(i=> i.MethodTwo("foo"), Times.Once());
}
```

This works fine...

I've tried these tests for determining a certain sequence is properly met, but the test seems to always pass.

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
    var mockSequence = new MockSequence();

    var obj = new MyClass();
    await obj.Run();

    mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodOne("foo"));
    mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodTwo("foo"));
}
```

Should pass, and does...

```
[TestMethod]
public async Task Test()
{
    var mock = new Mock<IInterface>();
    var mockSequence = new MockSequence();

    var obj = new MyClass();
    await obj.Run();

    mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodTwo("foo")); // swapped order here
    mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodOne("foo"));
}
```

Should not pass, but does...

1. What do I need to do differently to verify proper sequence is met?
2. How do I combine the two so that I can test number of execution times AND proper sequence?

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because the two questions seem to refer to the same issue. If they don't, let me know and I'll vote to reopen.

Comment: I read that question prior to asking this one. That question was resolved with an answer that said this was a bug in Moq. That was 3 years ago... I assume it's not a bug still.

Comment: i've reopened the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may be further off topic than you want to go but [NSubstitute](http://nsubstitute.github.io/) is a great mocking library that handles this very well. 
In NSubstitute it's just:

```
  var mock = Substitute.For<IInterface>();
  var obj = new MyClass();
  await obj.Run();

  Received.InOrder(() => {
    mock.MethodOne("foo");
    mock.MethodTwo("foo");
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'll give it a look. This seems to have much better docs than Moq.

Comment: Yeah and the API is a lot nicer to use.

Comment: Wow, you're right. This is way better. So much more intuitive. I'll give it a few to see if anyone can answer the question which is more specifically about Moq. If not, I'll give it to you.

Answer (score 11):

Your example tests for `InSequence` seem to be in the wrong order.  You should be performing the `Setup`, before you invoke the `Run` method.  I've assumed this is a typo and that your actual tests do the `Setup`, then invoke the object in the correct order.  It's also not clear how your mock of `IInterface` gets to `MyClass`.  In my final example, I've assumed it's actually injected...

Moq's `InSequence` support only seems to work if you're using strict mocks.  If you create your `Mock` like this:

```
var mock = new Mock<IInterface>(MockBehavior.Strict);
```

Then this will work:

```
mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodOne("foo"));
mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodTwo("foo"));
```

while this fails:

```
mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodTwo("foo")); // swapped order here
mock.InSequence(mockSequence).Setup(i => i.MethodOne("foo"));
```

Note, the error that comes is about the method missing a corresponding setup... rather than it being called out of sequence, which isn't necessarily the easiest to decode if you're not expecting it.

The alternate approach, if you don't want to / can't use strict mocks is to implement your own sequence checking using callbacks.  Something like this:

```
int sequence = 1;

mock.Setup(i => i.MethodOne("foo"))
    .Callback(()=>Assert.AreEqual(1, sequence++, "Method called out of sequence"));
mock.Setup(i => i.MethodTwo("foo"))
    .Callback(() => Assert.AreEqual(2, sequence++, "Method called out of sequence"));

var obj = new MyClass(mock.Object);
await obj.Run();
```